# Android OpenCV FaceDetection test application error

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I have downloaded the latest OpenCV SDK for Android and I tried to run the face-detection application sample. I have correctly set the module dependency and the java calls to native OpenCV can be executed. However, calling OpenCV C++ code from another native module is not available. Seems that linking the native libraries is not properly done and the following error is observed:

[image]

I have followed the official tutorial and all the native libraries are copied to the `jniLibs` folder. The structure of the application is as follows:

[image]

Has anyone been able to work on the native side of OpenCV in Android Studio and can give some advice or redirect to any good working tutorial online?

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with your Android.mk file. Could you post the content of that file?

This is how I included opencv in the Android.mk file.

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := opencv
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/libopencv_java3.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And my includes

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES        += $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/opencv
```